# Django 1.9: Should I avoid importing models during `django.setup()`?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.9

Porting my app to django 1.9, I got the scary `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`

Basically my stacktrace is:

```
  manage.py
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  django/core/management:352, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  django/core/management/__init__.py:326, in execute
    django.setup()
  django/__init__.py:18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  django/apps/registry.py:85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  django/apps/config.py:90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  python2.7/importlib/__init__.py:37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  myapp/mylib/__init__.py:52, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType   #<= The important part
  django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:159, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  django/db/models/base.py:94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  django/apps/registry.p:239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  django/apps/registry.py:124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

My main question here :

**Should I import my models in the `__init__.py` of my django apps ?**

It seems to trigger the `django.models.ModelBase` metaclass that check if the app is ready before creating the model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Should I import my models in the `__init__.py` of my django apps ?

No, you **must** not import any model in the `__init__.py` file of any installed app. This is no longer possible in 1.9.

From the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9):

> All models need to be defined inside an installed application or
>   declare an explicit app_label. Furthermore, it isn’t possible to
>   import them before their application is loaded. **In particular, it
>   isn’t possible to import models inside the root package of an
>   application.**